# Paypal subscription integration and revise subscription issues

Tags: angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I'm working with angular project where my requirement is to configure paypal payment gateway with create subscription, cancel subscription, upgrade subscription.

**I'm having 2 problem with paypal as described below:**

**1) I've successfully Rendered paypal button with below code:**

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=client_id_here&disable-funding=credit,card&vault=true"></script>
```

**payment.component.ts**

```
const self = this;  
this.planId = localStorage.getItem("paypalPlanId");  //Default Plan Id

paypal.Buttons({  
  createSubscription: function (data, actions) {  
    
    return actions.subscription.create({  
      'plan_id': self.planId,
      "subscriber": {
        "name": {
          "given_name": localStorage.getItem("fullName").split(' ')[0],
          "surname": localStorage.getItem("fullName").split(' ')[1]
        },
        "email_address": localStorage.getItem("email")
      }
    });  
  },
  onApprove: function (data) {  
    console.log(data); 
    self.getSubcriptionDetails();
    self.router.navigate(CC_GLOBAL.PAYMENT_THANKS_ROUTE);
  },  
  onCancel: function (data) {  
    // Show a cancel page, or return to cart  
    console.log(data);  
  },  
  onError: function (err) {  
    // Show an error page here, when an error occurs  
    console.log(err);  
  }  

}).render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
```

Above code is working as expected and able to create subscription.
Now my requirement is quite different, as mentioned below:

After clicking on **paypal** button, it is opening modal popup and after successful login attempt I'm able to subscribe plan.

I've also setup webhook methods with my account, after successful subscription it is calling webhook methods and while calling webhook method response is being return with loggedIn user details (EMAIL, first/last name) instead of above email and user first/last name.

Above **createSubscription method** working as expected sometimes but sometimes it's not.

Got reference of above code from official doc of paypal.

**2) Paypal upgrade plan **REST API** returns an error:**

I'm having subscription id and taken reference from here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/subscriptions/add-capabilities/revise-subscriptions/

but is's returning below error:

**Invalid subscription status for revise action; subscription status should be active.**

how could I know about active status, I'm using **Sandbox account**

Comment: The subscription should be active after successfully reaching the onApprove code. Are you trying to revise it before that?  You can get the status with: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_get , but you shouldn't need to do this

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually I've tried to revise subscription after an hour and so. but same issue and it's not working at all.

Comment: Okay, then wait 24 hours for the first cycle to bill

Comment: Ohk..No issue! Do you have solution for my first problem ?

Comment: Not enough details about the error, reproduce it with the dev tools Network tab open and check the console as well

Comment: Yes tried it as well, not sure why it works sometimes but sometimes it's not :(

Comment: Get logs for the cases where it doesn't work, should be a 400 or 500 error, hopefully with some legible message, but at least a PayPal-Debug-Id / Correlation ID from the body or Response Headers of the 400/500

Comment: Yes you are right, but I'm having paypal button not rest API now in this case it just open popup => request for payment and returns success, how can we look logs for the same?
in the case of rest api we can get the error logs but here It's returning success only.

Comment: Open the button on your site. Open the Network tab in dev tools. Clear all history in your javascript console and in the Network tab. Enable "Preserve log" in the network tab.  Then, reproduce the problem.  Observe what is logged in the console and in your browser's network tab.

Comment: Ok thnkas! will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I did some research on this questions and found below paypal bugs:

**1) https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1336**

**2) https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1247#issuecomment-551066663**

Still I'm looking for answer for the same.